# How to insert NULL AS alias "dummy columns" for UNION in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

## Context

Suppose I have a model class in SQLAlchemy that looks something like this:

```
class A():
   id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   title = Column('Title', String, nullable=False)
   type = Column('type', String)
   message = Column('message', String, nullable=False)
```

If I filter this model class using `query()` like this:
`q = session.query(A)`
The output is the following:

```
SELECT 
"A"."id" AS "A_id", "A"."title" AS "A_title", "A"."type" AS "A_type", "A"."message" AS "A_message" 
FROM "A"
```

#### Problem

I need to perform a `UNION` with another query that contains the same number of columns, in the same order.
I need my query to be this:

```
SELECT 
NULL AS "A_id", NULL AS "A_title", NULL AS "A_type", NULL AS "A_message" 
FROM "A"
```

I've already tried:
`q = session.query(A, null())`
but that just returns:

```
SELECT 
"A"."id" AS "A_id", "A"."title" AS "A_title", "A"."type" AS "A_type", "A"."message" AS "A_message", NULL AS anon_1
FROM "A"
```

## Question

```
SELECT 
NULL AS "A_id", NULL AS "A_title", NULL AS "A_type", NULL AS "A_message" 
FROM "A"
```

How can I achieve the query shown above (inserting `NULL AS` as an alias)?

Comment: `null().label('A_id')` etc?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes that is what I'm trying to achieve, however, is there a way to automate it so that it applies the `null()` for each column in a model class?
This doesn't work but something like: `null().label(for each column in A)`